# How to turn off NavigationLink overlay color in SwiftUI?

Tags: xcode, colors, navigation, swiftui

I've designed a "CardView" using ZStack in which the background layer is a gradient and the foreground layer is a PNG(or PDF) image(the image is a yellow path(like a circle) drawn in Adobe Illustrator).

When I put the ZStack inside a NavigationLink the gradient remains unchanged and fine, but the image get a bluish overlay color (like default color of a button) therefore there is no more yellow path(the path is bluish).

How can get the original color of foreground PNG(or PDF) image?

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct MyCardView : View {
    let cRadius : CGFloat = 35
    let cHeight : CGFloat = 220
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Hello")) {
                ZStack {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: cRadius)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .opacity(0)
                        .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color(red: 109/255, green: 58/255, blue: 242/255),Color(red: 57/255, green: 23/255, blue: 189/255)]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing), cornerRadius: 0)
                        .cornerRadius(cRadius)
                        .frame(height: cHeight)
                        .padding()
                    Image("someColoredPathPNGimage")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The `navigationLink` acts like `Button` and it gets the default button style with blue color.

Using `.renderingMode(.original)` only works on `Image` views. What if you decide to load your image using some libs or pods?!

It is better to change the default button style to plain using the modifier below:

```
NavigationLink(destination: Text("Hello")) {
    ZStack {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: cRadius)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .opacity(0)
            .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color(red: 109/255, green: 58/255, blue: 242/255),Color(red: 57/255, green: 23/255, blue: 189/255)]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing), cornerRadius: 0)
            .cornerRadius(cRadius)
            .frame(height: cHeight)
            .padding()
        Image("someColoredPathPNGimage")
    }
}
.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())  // Here is what you need
```

Comment: Thank you for this tip ! I did not know how to build a custom navigation button (using text and image). You made my day.

Comment: Thank you very much! This made my day also!!!

Answer (score 16):

Add `.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())` to the NavigationLink(....)

```
NavigationLink(
   destination: Text("Destination"),
   label: {
       Text("Click Here!")
   }
)
.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```

Comment: Working fine on iOS 15+ also

Comment: did not work for me on iOS 15+ :(

Answer (score 12):

Try:

```swift
Image("someColoredPathPNGimage").renderingMode(.original)
```

If your problems continue, consider uploading a screenshot so we get an idea of what you mean. If you can include the image you are using, even better, so we can replicate.

Answer (score 1):

You change colour with accentColor modifier

```
 NavigationLink(
   destination: Text("Destination"),
   label: {
       Text("Click Here!")
   }
)
.accentColor(Color.black)
```

Comment: This is the right answer iOS 15.6+