# SwiftUI: navigate to another view with .onTapGuesture{}

Tags: navigation, swiftui

For the following `CardView()`, I want the user to tap on it to navigate to the a `WebView()` with the link string in `post.article_url`.

```
ForEach(self.posts.reversed(), id: \.id) {post in
    GeometryReader{geo -> AnyView in
        return AnyView(
            CardView (index: self.getPostIndex(post: post),
                      title: post.title,
                      image: post.cover_image,
                      author: post.author, 
                      source: post.source, description: post.description,
                      imageWidth: self.cardWidth, 
                      imageHeight: self.imageHeight(index: self.getPostIndex(post: post))
            )
            .animation(.spring())
            .frame(width: self.widthAmount(index: self.getPostIndex(post: post)), 
                   height: self.heightAmount(index: self.getPostIndex(post: post)))
            .offset(x: self.CardOffsetAmountHorizontal(index: self.getPostIndex(post: post)),
                    y: self.CardOffsetAmountVertical(index: self.getPostIndex(post: post)))
            .onTapGesture{
                // navigate to a webview with url: post.article_url
            }
        )}}
```

I tried to wrap `CardView()` with `NavigationLink()`. The navigation is successful, but it turned the image and text on the `CardView()` into complete blue. Maybe this can be solved through some other means (such as with some codes in `.onTapGuesture{}`)?

Also, as this is a card stack that is supposed to be swiped. The `NavigationLink()` also blocks the dragging gesture on these cards.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This should solve the issue of the blue color in the NavigationLink [How to turn off NavigationLink overlay color in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57177989/how-to-turn-off-navigationlink-overlay-color-in-swiftui)

Comment: This explains how to use NavigationLink programmatically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57889990/use-navigationlink-programmatically-in-swiftui

Comment: @Andrew Thanks, but this works only for `Image()` views. This `CardView()` contains a customized `UrlImageView()`  that fetches image from url. And if I use `.renderingMode(.original)` on `CardView()` directly, it will have an error and crash the app.

Comment: Then your customised UrlImageView should use the renderingMode at the appropriate point, on the underlying Image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introduce a variable (Bool) which you monitor with an empty NavigationLink. When capturing the tab toggle this variable which will then activate the Redirect

```
// This variable 
@State private var goToNewView: Bool = false

ForEach(self.posts.reversed(), id: \.id) {post in
    GeometryReader{geo -> AnyView in
        return AnyView(
            CardView (index: self.getPostIndex(post: post),
                      title: post.title,
                      image: post.cover_image,
                      author: post.author, 
                      source: post.source, description: post.description,
                      imageWidth: self.cardWidth, 
                      imageHeight: self.imageHeight(index: self.getPostIndex(post: post))
            )
            .animation(.spring())
            .frame(width: self.widthAmount(index: self.getPostIndex(post: post)), 
                   height: self.heightAmount(index: self.getPostIndex(post: post)))
            .offset(x: self.CardOffsetAmountHorizontal(index: self.getPostIndex(post: post)),
                    y: self.CardOffsetAmountVertical(index: self.getPostIndex(post: post)))
            .onTapGesture{
                // navigate to a webview with url: post.article_url

                // Toggle the variable here
                self.goToNewView.toggle()
            }
        )}}


// Put this in your view. It will not be visible
NavigationLink(destination: MyOtherView(), isActive: self.$goToNewView) { EmptyView() }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I also added another state variable to carry along the article url. However, when I close the new page, it will reopen itself again somehow. And only if I close it for the second time will it not show up again. Is there a way to modify the new page programmatically? For example, when I turn this off, I can make `goToNewView = false`? Moreover, the top bar with "back" button has occupied more than one line (and at least three lines) of spaces. Can I also modify that?

Comment: It should not reopen the ```MyOtherView``` when going back unless you press again. When you go back the State of ```goToNewView``` will be set back to false. There seems to be an issue somewhere else in our code.