# How do you change the select color of a navigation link in a list

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

This seams like a simple question, but I can’t find the answer anywhere on google.

When a navigation link is in a list, you can change the color of it to blue with:

```
.listRowBackground(Color.blue)
```

But when the navigation link is selected, it turns to systemGray4

[image: Image for reference]

How do I change the select color of a navigation link in a list

Here is the sample project in the image above:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
        List {
            NavigationLink("Hello", destination: Text("hello"))
                .listRowBackground(Color.blue)
            NavigationLink("World", destination: Text("world"))
                .listRowBackground(Color.blue)
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to turn off NavigationLink overlay color in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57177989/how-to-turn-off-navigationlink-overlay-color-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you keep track of the selected tab, then you can specifically set the color of the list row for the tab that is selected.

Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    enum Tab: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
        case hello
        case world

        var id: String { rawValue }

        var title: String {
            switch self {
            case .hello: return "Hello"
            case .world: return "World"
            }
        }
    }

    @State private var selectedTab: Tab?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(Tab.allCases) { tab in
                    NavigationLink(tab.title, tag: tab, selection: $selectedTab) {
                        Text(tab.rawValue)
                    }
                    .listRowBackground(tab == selectedTab ? Color.accentColor : nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*When recording a gif of this on the simulator, for some reason it doesn't work properly. Not sure if that's a bug.*

Comment: Could you explain what the enum tab part is doing, sorry, I’m very new to swift ui.

Comment: @MalachyFernandez Sure - the enum has a case for each tab. The enum case for the selected tab is stored in `selectedTab`. When the tab is changed by clicking on a different list row, the `selectedTab` changes. You could use a string for this instead, but this is neater and you don't have the risk of typos breaking selection. The enum is also used to loop over each case and create a tab, rather than repeating code.

Comment: Ah I understand. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could change the property `.selectionStyle` of `UITableViewCell.appearance()`.
In the `init` of your View or when the List appears :

```
.onAppear {
     UITableViewCell.appearance().selectionStyle = .none
}
```

and continue to manage the highlight color of your links with `listRowBackground`

Comment: This doesn't work in iOS 15.5, XCode 13.4.1 - I haven' t tested in other versions

Comment: It still works for me with Xcode 13.4/iOS15.5, Xcode 13.4/iOS14.5, Xcode 14/iOS16 