# How do I set the selected row background color in a SwiftUI List?

Tags: list, swiftui

I am using a standard List in SwiftUI and would like to modify the selected rows' background color.

Here is the code:

```
...
List {
    ForEach(recipesToShow, id: \.self) { recipe in
        NavigationLink(destination: RecipeDetailWrapper(recipe: recipe)) {
            RecipeListRow(recipe: recipe)
                .environmentObject(recipeDateFormatter)
        }
    }
    .onDelete(perform: deleteRecipe)
} //: LIST
.listStyle(PlainListStyle())
...
```

This is how it looks by default:

[image: Selected Row background color]

Comment: Well, this is a first. Looks like I've stumped the entire community. Still hoping someone will offer some valuable insights.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the modifier .listRowBackground(Color.blue) to modify the background color of your list.

For the specific item, I would add a state var to store the id of the element tapped and then evaluate it in each item of the list,

you can check the answer here:

[How do you change the select color of a navigation link in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68772557/how-do-you-change-the-select-color-of-a-navigation-link-in-a-list)

that I think is what you need.

Comment: Thank you for providing this information. Unfortunately neither option works. I will circle back when I find the solution.